# Конвертация из byte[] в Stream. Русские буквы заменяются на ???????

Tags: c#, конвертация, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте! Проблема в конвертации массива байт в поток (русские буквы заменяются на знаки вопроса)

По сокету получаю сообщение размером totalByte и записываю его в массив байт byteMsg. Для дальнейшей работы мне нужно ковертировать это сообщение в поток Stream.

Если конвертировать массив байт в строку - все впорядке, русские буквы отображаются нормально.

Когда конвертирую в поток, русские буквы заменяются на знаки вопроса. Для проверки перевожу обратно в строку и вывожу в лог.

```
string text1 = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteMsg);
text1 = text1.Substring(0, totalByte);

Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteMsg, 0, totalByte);
stream.Position = 0;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string text2 = reader.ReadToEnd();

log.Debug("text 1 = " + text1);
log.Debug("text 2 = " + text2);
```

В логах вижу:

```
text 1 = русские буквы
text 2 = ??????? ?????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете конструктор StreamReader без явного указания кодировки. Вот цитата с [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-6.0):

> Этот конструктор в качестве кодировки
> задает UTF8Encoding, инициализирует
> свойство BaseStream, используя
> параметр stream, и задает размер
> внутреннего буфера 1024 байта.

Вы же данные получаете с помощью кодировки `Encoding.Default` (чего, на сколько я знаю, делать вообще [не рекомендуется](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/shawnste/dont-use-encoding-default)), которая возвращает (опять же цитата с [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-6.0))

> Получает кодировку для текущей кодовой
> страницы ANSI операционной системы.

А результат, собственно, Вы и наблюдаете

**UPDATE**

@masuhorukov, никакой конвертации из byte[] в Stream нет. Stream - это просто поток байт и Вы в него байты же и запихиваете, какая тут может быть конвертация? Вам вообще не обязательно данные в Stream тащить через MemoryStream.

Допустим что кодировка на сервере `Windows-1251`, которая совпадает (опять же предположительно) с Вашей `Encoding.Default` (потому что на сервере Вы скорее всего так же и писали). Когда вы просто декодируете байты в строку (в первых двух строчках кода) то все в порядке, т.к. для кодирования и декодирования используется одна и та же кодировка. Однако, потом вы массив байт, полученных с помощью кодировки `Windows-1251` помещаете в `Stream`, обёрнутый в `StreamReader` который в свою очередь по умолчанию работает с кодировкой `UTF8`, а когда вы считываете эти данные из `StreamReader` с помощью `ReadToEnd`, `StreamReader` переводит байты в строку с помощью кодировки `UTF8`. Теперь видите нестыковочку?

Comment: Дело в том, что при конвертации из массива байт в поток кодировка нигде не указывается. И в потоке уже находятся неправильные символы. 

Вообще это сообщение в формате протобафа и дальше после десериализации и парсинга полей я вижу неправильные символы. 

Собственно поэтому и подумал, что проблема именно в конвертации из byte[] в Stream

Comment: @masuhorukov, обновил ответ. В комментарий не входит

Comment: *"Stream, который в свою очередь по умолчанию работает с кодировкой UTF8"* - что я только что прочитал?

Comment: Поправил ответ.